# Can association between package and actor be made?

Tags: uml

Can it be done like this? I know I can make one actor which generalize behaviour of two on the left, but I need to know if this case shown below is possible.

[image: Two actors with association to package, one actor with association only to use case which package contains.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can do quite a lot with UML this does not look ok (though I can't cite Superstructures about any constraints). But what you can do is to use a dependency instead. That would be perfectly ok.

The question still would stand: what kind of dependency will you show? That's what a reader of the model comes up with. If you can answer that, it's ok. Else you should sit down and think...